# JavaScript error with formatting Date objects

Tags: javascript, date

I am receiving a very specific logic error in my code and I am not sure what is causing it. I have a function `formatDate()` which gets the current date and puts it in the format yyyy-mm-dd. To achieve this, I have to add a "0" to the front of the month or day when it is a single digit (smaller than 10).

I have written this code to do this:

```
let year = currentDate.getFullYear();
let month = currentDate.getMonth() < 10 ? "0" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) : currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
let date = currentDate.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + currentDate.getDate() : currentDate.getDate();
```

However, when I do `console.log(year + "-" + month + "-" + date)`, I get this:

```
2020-010-24
```

As you can see, the zero is not added to the `date` but it is added to the `month`, despite both variables having the exact same logic. I have no idea what is causing this.

Comment: Side note: You might consider: `let month = String(currentDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0");`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason you can't use a standard function like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString for this and then modify it, rather than writing the whole thing from scratch?

Comment: Side note 2: `getMonth` and such on JavaScript dates aren't just simple accessors, they have to do work to go from the underlying milliseconds-since-the-Epoch value to a local timezone month value. Usually it doesn't matter, but if you're giong to use `current.getMonth()` in three different places *anyway*, calling it once and reusing the result could simplify things (and avoid the error that hoangdv points out below).

Comment: I strongly recommend to use `dayjs` to format the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`currentDate.getMonth()` returns `9`, this mean your condition `currentDate.getMonth() < 10` became `true`, then it appends "0" to `month` variable.

Get "correct" month value then make the condition:

```
let month = (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? "0" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) : currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
```